# Insert cell at indexPath, not working correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with objects in it (such as `UILabel`, `UITextView`, `UITextField` etc.). When a button gets selected, a `cell` gets added to the `tableView`.

When I run it on the simulator, and the cell gets added, all the visible cell's and subviews height get really compact. (I do have auto constraint applied.)

```
....
[[self myTableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

If I do the following, the cells get back to normal:

```
NSArray* visibleCellIndex = self.myTableView.indexPathsForVisibleItems;
[self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleCellIndex withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:savedScrollPosition inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

The problem with reloading the visible cells, is: First, that's a workaround, not getting to the source of the problem. Second, it's not a fully functioning workaround, because the whole `tableView` scrolls all the way up for a second, then scroll back to position.

Comment: Are you wrapping insertRowsAtIndexPaths with "[myTableView beginUpdates]" and "[myTableView endUpdates]"?

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't help. The same thing happens.

Comment: Is anything uninitialized, such that their values are undefined, and just happen to work out properly on the phone by chance? Are you sure your constraints are set up properly? No warnings in Interface Builder, or if you created them manually, have you tried UIView's sizeToFit() method?

Comment: Are you saying the size of the visible cells all shrink uniformly, or do they shrink a combined total equal to the height of the inserted cells?  What does your heightForRowAtIndexPath look like, and is this an iOS 8+ app?

Comment: @jeffro37 I was just about to check if they shrink uniformly or not, when I realized I didn't have `heightForRow...`!! When I added that method it didn't shrink, but it gave me a different problem. If I add a certain amount of cells, then the `tableView` first scrolls up, then scrolls to location.]

Comment: Does anyone know why it scrolls to top then back down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it was shrinking, is because, you have to implement the method of `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

The only problem now, is that the `tableView` jumps up, then scrolls to position. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Does your target run only on iOS 8 and later? If yes, you can set `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to enable Autolayout for your cells. Then, you also don't need to implement delegate `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

If you're already doing this, your problem probably lies in your custom cell. Maybe its constraints are not well defined? How do you initialize the cell's constraints?

Another idea is to trigger the layout pass manually in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. After the cell has been initialized and its text label values have been set, call:

```
[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: I solved the problem for the shrinking cells, (see my comments,) but now the problem is that every time I add a new cell, the tableview scrolls up for a second, then goes back to position.

Comment: Could you provide a full class example? It would make helping you a lot easier.